# Select which files to 'require' at run-time - node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a parser for a language I'm implementing and I would like to allow the user to issue a request to use outside implementations of their own functions in a .js file they create. So, for example:

**functions.js**

```
var functions = {
    var func1 = function(){/*...*/}
}

module.exports = functions;
```

**toparse.mylanguage**

```
#bind "functions.js"
x = func1();
```

And in my node.js server I would use `var functions = require('./functions')` and have the parser direct the execution to the relevant function. I assume that they upload the .js file to the same folder they uploade the .mylanguage file.

What would be a good way to do this?

EDIT: to clarify, I don't know the name of the .js file before `#bind` is used, so I can't `require` it specifically beforehand.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12140791/1538708

Comment: @adamb Thanks! Will this block the whole server? Any way around it if so?

Comment: Good question... I'm not sure. May be worth opening a second SO question if this becomes a performance issue.