# JS On-demand require() in main file

Tags: javascript, require, ondemand

Say I have a root.js which is requiring certain file, like :

```
var x = require('x.js');
var y = require('y.js');

function f_x() { return x.foo(); }
function f_y() { return y.foo(); }

f_y();  // This logic only needs y to get resolved
```

Thus in such a case, how can we load y only when f_y() occurs, i.e., it is on-demand. 
This is the solution for on-demand require in the required file ('x.js' or 'y.js') : [On-demand require()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138983/on-demand-require/12140791#12140791) 
But since there is no exports in the root file, thus its getters can't be defined like that.

Answer (score 2):

You can delay the `require` call until it's needed like this:

```js
function f_x() {
  var x = require('./x.js');
  return x.foo();
}
function f_y() {
  var y = require('./y.js');
  return y.foo();
}

f_y();
```

Comment: Thanks @Always Learning, I am aware of this method. But I was looking to write a script to update such files automatically. Needless to say, in this approach there would be many cases to handle and a lot of code change. Perhaps some wrapper, with minimal changes, would be better.